# How do I change the icon for a chatbot in Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I used bot framework to create a chatbot and connected it to messenger on my companies Facebook Page. I got the right permissions and the chatbot runs great.

The icon shown before each message of the chatbot is the icon of my companies Facebook page.
I would like to use a customer avatar for this to make the experience more personal.

What did I already try?

- I uploaded the icon in App Dashboard, Settings, Basic
- I submitted the app for review again
- I got a message that the new App icon was approved.

But still the new icon does not show up in messenger.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: I don’t think that is possible. From the user perspective, the page _is_ the entity they are chatting with.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for your view on this.